# Validated data is empty

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I use Django REST Frameworke in my application. I want to create like for posts

My api view:

```py
class LikePostAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    model = Like
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]
    serializer_class = LikeCreateSerializer
```

My LikeCreateSerializer:

```py
class LikeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Like
        fields = ('post_id', )
```

I send JSON data:

```json
{
    "post_id": 1
}
```

But i get 500 HTTP status because my validated_data is empty in serializer

Comment: add the field to the serializer post_id = serializer.IntegerField()

Comment: Can you share your "Like" model? I think maybe you have a foreign key to Post model, in that case you should update your fields: "fields = ('post')". Also you should send  the JSON data as: { "post": 1 }